# JavaScript Does Not Load On Any Browser

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/LThhd/8/

Here is the source, I honestly have no idea why it won't load :(

Comment: The js script isn't functioning in the bottom right. It should be pushing lines across the window.

Comment: The reason fiddle isn't working is b/c jQuery 1.8.2 isn't being loaded. Check the console. With that said I can see the quantifiedXPos being called and logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is causing an error because `restart()` is not defined in the global scope:

```
setInterval('restart()', EVENT_RESTART_INTERVALL);
```

In your jsFiddle, all your javascript is inside the `onload()` handler function so none of your functions are global.  You need to either make the restart function be a truly global function so `setInterval()` can find it at the top level or you need to change to a function reference and define `restart()` in some scope that the setInterval line can see:

```
setInterval(restart, EVENT_RESTART_INTERVALL);
```

FYI, this is one of the reasons why it's a bad idea to pass strings to `setInterval()`.  Function references are much easier to control because they can be anywhere in scope - don't have to only be global functions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is...

Comment: @ianpgall - No, it's not in your jsFiddle because you have it set to onLoad which means all your javascript is inside an onload function handler (none of it is global).

Comment: So what do you suggest I do to fix it?

Comment: @EllisonPatterson - Read the rest of my answer.  Either define restart to be a truly global function, change the jsFiddle to not be onload or use a local function reference instead of a string for `setInterval()`.  Your choice.

Comment: @jfriend00 I see what you mean. You didn't have that explanation before. At first, you only explained it's not in the global scope, so you must've edited your answer. That makes perfect sense now

Comment: @Ellison Patterson (@ianpgall): you suffer from multiple personality disorder?

Comment: I think the OP didn't mean to make the jsFiddle be "onload" - they clearly are trying to go about things as if they were in the `<head></head>` section. They even have document.ready in the code

Comment: @KooiInc Haha I guess so. I'm not sure why this has become "mine"...

Comment: I've been modifying a source to work on all browsers and I was just following JSLink. Source is here:
https://github.com/otw/Nexus-JS-live-wallpaper/blob/master/nexusLive.js

Comment: @EllisonPatterson - when I fix the `setInterval()` in the jsFiddle, the code runs.  I don't know what it's supposed to do, but I can see regular output in the console running from the interval timer.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need to add `http://` to your url imports